# Web Activity endless running In Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently it seems that web activity is broken.

When using simple pipeline

```
 {
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Webactivity",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/",
                    "connectVia": {
                        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "body": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

When debugging it never finishes. There is "in progress" for several minutes.
I tried Web hook and it works.

Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found it.

The default AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime only had managed private network which I couldn't change. So I created a new Integration Runtime with public network setting.
This is a litte bit strange as I started today with a brand new Azure Data Factory.

[image]

**I wonder why I cannot change the default Integration Runtime to disable virtual network:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick note on the "never finishes" issue: one of my pet peeves with Data Factory is that the default timeout for all activities is 7 DAYS. While I've had a few activities that needed to run for 7 hours, a WEEK is a ridiculous default timeout value. One of the first things I do in any production scenario is address the timeout values of all the activities.

As to the Web activity question: I set up a quick example in my test bed and it returned just fine:

[image]

Looking at the generated code, the only real difference I see is the absence of the "connectVia" property that was in your example:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried again but no success. I've set the timeout to 10 seconds and now I get a "Timed Out" Status. How is the configuration of your Integration runtime?